# custom online buillder ckeditor doesn't show all tools

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor 5 in my react(next.js) project. default editor toolbar is not suitable for this case and many plugins that I need doesn't exist in default version of ckeditor. So I used online builder(https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and added my custom editor to the project using this approach:  https://www.datainfinities.com/3/how-to-integrate-custom-build-ckeditor5-with-react .

But the problem is many plugins that I've added, doesn't exist in my ckeditor! for example I installed:

- find and replace
- auto format
- code block
- ckbox

and I can see them in package.json of custom ckeditor folder:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^36.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autosave": "^36.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^36.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^36.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox": "^36.0.0",
...}
```

but I can't see any of these plugins in my ckeditor and I only see this:
[image]

Comment: have u solved it? facing same issue . even my heading tool is not working properly

Comment: No. now I'm using tinyMCE instead!